# A rospy subscriber callback thread locking question

Tags: ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a rospy node that has both a main loop and a subscriber callback that both need to modify the same global variable and I'm wondering if I have to use thread locking to prevent weirdness.  The following snippet exhibits what I mean.  Does the variable self.move_cmd.angular.z need locking in this situation?

```
def __init__():
    rospy.init_node("test")

    rospy.subscriber('roi', RegionOfInterest, self.roi_callback)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        if not target_visible:
            self.move_cmd.angular.z = 0
            
        rospy.sleep(1)

def roi_callback(self, msg):
    if msg.width !=0 and msg.height != 0:
       self.move_cmd.angular.z = 0.1 * msg.x_offset
```

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115251/a-rospy-subscriber-callback-thread-locking-question/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since callbacks in rospy are processed in a separate thread, I'm pretty sure you need locking for a case like this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2014-01-07**:
Thanks Austin.  I'll lock it up.